# JSLint: Unexpected assignment expression

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jslint

I get this warning:

```
Unexpected assignment expression.
return task.completed = true; // Line 63, Pos 39
```

When using this code:

```
completeAll: function () {
    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
        return task.completed = true;
    });
}
```

Why? And how else could I write this expression to avoid JSLint throwing warnings?

P.S.

The codeblock is taken from the Vue TodoMVC Example here: http://todomvc.dev/examples/vue/, therefore I assume that code review must have already been happened.

Comment: @Tushar: You mean `return task.completed;` (or `return true;`). Although `return task;` would work (non-`null` object references being truthy), its misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doing that because it's warning you that you're using `=` rather than `==` or `===` in a context where you're not just assigning, but also doing something with the assigned result. That's perfectly valid JavaScript, but it's frequently unintentional. A better example is:

```
if (foo = bar) {
    // ...
}
```

...where you probably meant `==` or `===` (checking that they were equal).

How you fix it depends on what you're trying to do. From the name of the method, I assume you're (well, they're) trying to set `task.completed`, in which case frankly `filter` is the wrong function to use; they should be using `forEach`:

```
completeAll: function () {
    this.tasks.forEach(function (task) {
        task.completed = true;
    });
}
```

but if you (they) really wanted to use `filter`:

```
completeAll: function () {
    this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(function (task) {
        task.completed = true;
        return true; // Or return task.completed
    });
}
```

If you're trying to do a comparison (which I doubt), not an assignment, then:

```
return task.completed == true;
```

or

```
return !!task.completed;
```

or

```
return task.completed; // If you know it's boolean already
```